# What is Shri Venkateshwara Mangalasasana stotram recited for?

Tags: stotra, venkateshwara

What is Shri Venkateshwara Mangalasasana Stotram recited for?

Where can I find original text with meaning? (as it's hard to find flawless text on internet)

Comment: http://antaryami.net/darpanam/2013/10/19/sri-venkatesa-mangalasasanam/

Answer (score 7):

‘Srī Venkateśvara Mangalāsāsanam’ literally means ‘auspicious wishes to Srī Venkateśvara’. It is a Stotra written by the SriVaishnava saint Svāmi Prativādi Bhayaṅkaram Aṇṇā.

Hoping that you can read Sanskrit transliterations, I am attaching the text below:

> **1.  śriyaḥ-kānṭāya kalyāṇa-nidhaye nidhayerthināṃ 
>
>   śrīveṇkaṭa-nivāsāya śrīnivāsāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to the Lord Śrīnivāsa, who is the beloved of Sri, who is the sea of auspicious attributes, who is the abode of Goddess Lakshmi and who is the greatest wealth for those who seek Him!
>
> **2.  lakṣmī-savibhramāloka-subhrūvibhrama-cakṣuse 
>
>   cakṣuse sarvalokānāṃ veṅkateśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa of beautiful brows and beautiful eyes which are ever occupied in admiring the extraordinary charm of Goddess Lakṣmī and who is the Eye (the most precious one) of the world!
>
> **3.  śrīveṅkaṭādri-śṛngāgra-maṅgalābharanāṅghraye 
>
>   maṅgalānāṃ nivāsāya śrīnivāsāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness unto Lord Śrīnivāsa, whose lotus feet are the auspicious ornaments decorating the head of Sri Venkatadri, and who, being the abode of Goddess Śrī (Lakṣmī) , is the storehouse of all auspiciousness!
>
> **4.  sarvāvaya-saundarya-sampadā sarvacetasāṃ 
>
>   sadā sammohanāyāstu vēṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa, whose beautiful form makes everyone fall forever in love with Him!
>
> **5.  nityāya niravadyāya satyānanda-cid-ātmane 
>
>   sarvāntarātmane śrīmad veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Sri Veṅkateśa, who is eternal and blemishless, whose essential nature is truth, consciousness and bliss, and who is the inner soul of everything!
>
> **6.  svataḥ-sarvavide sarvaśaktaye sarvaśeṣiṇe 
>
>   sulabhāya suśīlāya veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa, who is omniscient by Himself, who is all capable, who is served by everyone, who is easy to approach and who mixes freely with His devotees!
>
> **7.  parasmai brahmaṇe pūrṇa-kāmāya paramātmane 
>
>   prayuñje paratatvāya veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa, who is the Ultimate Parabrahman, the Paramatma (Supersoul), the Supreme Truth, the Ultimate Cause and whose intentions are ever fulfilled!
>
> **8.  ākālatattvamaśrāntam-ātmanām-anupaśyatām 
>
>   atṛptamṛta-rūpāya veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa, who is the nectar that the souls are never satiated with, even as they relish Him with their eyes ceaselessly for as long as the principle of time exists!
>
> **9.  prāyaḥ svacaraṇau puṃsām śaraṇyatvena pāṇinā 
>
>   kṛpayā diśate śrīmad-veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Sri Venkatesa, who, out of great mercy, points His own right hand at His own lotus feet showing that His lotus feet, are the refuge for all!
>
> **10.  dayāmṛta-taraṅginyās-taraṅgair-iva śitalaiḥ 
>
>   apāṅgais-siñcate viśvaṃ veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness be unto Lord Veṅkateśa, from the corner of whose eyes, the river of mercy flows, drenching the universe with its cool waves!
>
> **11.  srag-bhūṣāmbara-hetīnāṃ suṣamāvaha-mūrtaye 
>
>   sarvārti-śamanāyāstu veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa, whose matchless divine form is that, which gives beauty to the garlands, ornaments, clothes and weapons adorned by Him and who destroys all the suffering of His devotees (simply by displaying the exquisite beauty of His enchanting form!
>
> **12.  śrīvaikuṇṭha-viraktāya svāmi-puṣkariṇī-taṭe 
>
>   ramayā ramamāṇāya veṅkaṭeśāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Sri Veṅkateśa, who, disinterested in staying at Sri Vaikunta, delights along with Goddess Lakṣmī, on the banks of the Svāmi puṣkariṇī, by engaging in playful sports with Her!
>
> **13.  śrīmat-sundarajāmātṛ-munimānasa-vāsine 
>
>   sarvaloka-nivāsāya śrinivāsāya maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to Lord Veṅkateśa, who resides in the heart of Svāmi Manāvala Māmunigal (Svāmi Manāvala Māmunigal, was the Guru of Svāmi Prativādi Bhayaṅkaram Aṇṇā) as much as He resides in all the worlds put together, and who is Himself the residence of Goddess Lakṣmī!
>
> **14.  maṅgalāśāsanaparaiḥ madācārya-purogamaiḥ 
>
>   sarvaiśca pūrvaiḥ ācāryaiḥ satkṛtāyāstu maṅgalam**
>
> All auspiciousness to the Lord, who was well worshipped by my Ācāryas and all the preceding Ācāryas, who are devoted to singing auspiciousness to Him!

Comment: Great Answer. What is the source?

Comment: @commonman There is no **PARTICULAR** source as such, because this is just a Mantra written by Prativadi Bhayankaram Anna.

Comment: Okay thanks. Few lines about that saints?

Comment: @commonman He was a SriVaishnava Saint who was born in Tamil Nadu. He was a disciple of Manavala Mamunigal (as mentioned in the answer), and is also known for composing Sri Venkateshvara Suprabhatham (which begins with “Kausalya Supraja Rama....”). He also composed Venkatesa Prapatti. Indeed, his cherished deity was Sri Venkateshvara...

Comment: Thanks so much.

Comment: http://antaryami.net/darpanam/2013/10/19/sri-venkatesa-mangalasasanam/